# ColdFusion ORM and default constructors (init method)

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-11

Hibernate requires a no-args constructor and in all languages that does support method overloading that's probably not an issue, but I've faced a really annoying issue in ColdFusion ORM (which relies on Hibernate under the hood).

If I declare a custom constructor (an init method) for my entities and that constructor requires some arguments, Hibernate fails to rehydrate my entities because it's calling the custom constructor.

Because of that behavior, it seems almost impossible to design always-valid entities and therefore makes CF-ORM close to being completely useless.

The only work-around I found is to declare another custom method that I use as a constructor which makes instanciating objects now look like `new SomeEntity().construct(...)` or `createObject('component', 'SomeEntity').construct(...)`. That's quite cumbersome...

What's very stupid in all this is that you can instanciate an entity without calling the `init` method using `createObject`, so I wonder why they decided to make Hibernate call the `init` method in their implementation, considering the fact that it's not even passing parameters and sets them afterwards by other means.

Anyway, is there any other work around for that issue?

EDIT:

[I filed a bug in the Adobe Bugbase](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4012852).

Comment: Because ORM cannot seem to handle 'always valid entities'  it is 'completely useless'? Please, explain.

Comment: @ScottStroz Well, if you are like me and believe entities should always be valid then you will not allow your classes to be instantiated without enforcing the invariants. E.g. if in my domain a `Person` concept must have a `name` then I wouldn't allow instantiating a `Person` component without one, but doing this will prevent me from using CF-ORM because the `init` function will be called without arguments when rehydrating the objects. That's not an issue in languages where the constructor can be overloaded.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'rehydrating' objects. Are you talking about when persisting an object, you need to pass in arguments that will pass in properties for that object? If so, you can simply use something like `new Person( {firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Johnson'})`. Though, I  believe this was introduced into CF10. You could always update.

Comment: @ScottStroz Rehydrating occurs when hibernate loads the data from the database and uses reflection to set the component values. With CF-ORM, Hibernate will call the component constructor like if it was a no argument constructor and therefore it will fail. Could you try that in CF10 and see what it gives? Make sure that your constructor arguments are made required.

Comment: OK....so that is not how I understood 'rehydrating', thanx for the clarification, though, it has lead to other confusion. Why/how are you using `createObject()` or `new Person()` to load data from the database? I am not sure that is the best method to retrieve entity data from the database in ColdFusion. I tend to use `entityLoad()` when loading multiple objects - or using multiple multiple criteria or `entityLoadByPK()` when I have the PK for a specific entity. Only time I would use `createObject()` or `new Person()` is when I am creating a new instance.

Comment: I would be happy to test something in ColdFusion 10 if you had sample code I could try.

Comment: @ScottStroz You are misunderstanding me. This is what I am saying. When you call `entityLoad`, Hibernate will rehydrate your entities. In order to do this, it will first call the constructor to create a new instances of the component and then it will use reflection to set the fields.

Comment: I understand that. What I do not understand is why this makes it 'completely useless'? Nor do I understand how using `createObject().constructor()` or `new Person().constructor()` allows you to load data from database and populate the properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [many efforts in making this request approved](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4012852), it has been fixed.

> Nimit Sharma
>
> 5:08:05 AM GMT+00:00 Nov 20, 2015
>
> This issue is fixed and the fix will be available as part of next
>   major release of ColdFusion.
>
> We have introduced a property "orminitmethod" at component level to
>   address this issue. Subcomponent do not inherit orminitmethod. It
>   behaves exactly like initmethod.
>
> I have logged another tracking bug #4090267 to have an application
>   level setting

Answer (score 0):

Always-valid entities rarely exist.  So having some sort of validate method could be one of the routes you can go with.

Or what you can do is continue to have your own object as is, and use ORM only in the DAO layer.  However you will have another set of similar classes, but yes, that's why people don't like ORMs.

Comment: Well, always-valid entities are a de facto in Domain-Driven Design (DDD). I do not whish to start a fight between the different shcool of thoughts, but IMHO entities allowed to be invalid may be fine in a simple CRUD domain with ActiveRecord but have no place in DDD. Also, I do not see how having an additionnal mapped abstraction will help in rehydrating the domain entitites? You would still need to map the new persistence-oriented entities to the domain objects. Hibernate is not a problem at all here, the issue comes from the poor ColdFusion implementation and it's very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

If an entity didn't have an empty constructor, then Hibernate would not know what parameters to provide when instantiating the entity.

You can make the default constructor `protected` and Hibernate will locate it, because `PojoInstantiator` uses the declared constructor:

```
constructor = ReflectHelper.getDefaultConstructor( mappedClass );
```

You can define a [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to construct the entities, instead of using overloaded constructors.

This way, you can impose that only the `Builder` is being used by your client API and not the default constructor.

Comment: Well, if I have to use a builder I guess I prefer using the `new Object().constructor()` approach. Using a builder for every classes would be a misuse of the pattern. Yet again, another think that makes ColdFusion such a poor enterprise language...